# Unable to access leafletData object in jasmine tests

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, leaflet

We are using angularjs with leaflet to display maps. Along with it we are using jasmine(1.3.1.5) + maven for the tests. In the specs written, we are unable to access the leafletData object. The controller goes like this:

```
  angular.module('TestProject').controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', 'leafletData',       
         function TestCtrl($scope, leafletData){
         'use strict';
          $scope.map;
          leafletData.getMap().then(function(map) {
                var southWest = L.latLng(-90, -180),
                northEast = L.latLng(90, 180),
                bounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
                mapObj.setMaxBounds(bounds);
                mapObj.options.maxZoom = 19;
                mapObj.options.minZoom = 1;
                $scope.map=map;
                $scope.featureGroup = L.featureGroup().addTo($scope.map);
      });
  }]);
```

The spec for the controller is:

```
   describe("test controller",function() {
        var scope,leafletData, compile;

        beforeEach(module("TestProject"));

        beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope, $compile, leafletData) {
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            compile = $compile;

            $controller('TestCtrl', {
                '$scope' : scope,
                'leafletData' : leafletData
            });
        }));

        it("test function", function() {
            var element = angular.element('<leaflet></leaflet>');
            element = compile(element)(scope);
            expect(leafletData).toBeDefined();
            leafletData.getMap().then(function(map) {
                scope.map = map;
            });
            $rootScope.$digest();
            expect(scope.map.getZoom()).toEqual(1);
            expect(scope.map.getCenter().lat).toEqual(0);
            expect(scope.map.getCenter().lng).toEqual(0);
        });

  });
```

And the error we are getting is:

1.) test controller it test function <<< FAILURE!
   * Expected undefined to be defined.
   * TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'leafletData.getMap') in            spec/controllers/testCtrlSpec.js (line 22)

We have specifically imported all the js files within angular-leaflet-directive but it doesn't seem to work. We also had the feeling that this could be an issue with the angular module name difference and we tried using beforeEach(module("TestProject", "leaflet-directive")); but this also did not solve our problem.

Please help us with this!!

Answer (score 2):

`leafletData` is not defined because it's declared at the top of the tests, but never has a value assigned to it. This is the general pattern to follow when bringing in injectables into your tests:

```
describe("test controller",function() {
    var leafletData;

    beforeEach(module("TestProject"));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_leafletData_) {
        // without this, leafletData will be undefined
        leafletData = _leafletData_;
    }));

    it("should be defined", function() {
        expect(leafletData).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

Moreover, when doing any unit testing, the code under test should be tested in isolation. Any services it relies on (i.e. `leafletData` in this case) and the responses from those services, should be mocked. For example:

```
describe("test controller",function() {
    var $q;
    var scope;
    var leafletData;

    var mockMapData = {
        // ...
        // some mock map data
        // ...
    };

    beforeEach(module("TestProject"));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_, _$q_, _leafletData_) {
        scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        $q = _$q_;
        leafletData = _leafletData_;

        // mock the leafletData
        spyOn(leafletData, 'getMap').andReturn($q.when(mockMapData));

        _$controller_('TestCtrl', {
            '$scope' : scope
        });
    }));

    it("test function", function() {
        scope.$digest();
        expect(scope.map).toEqual(mockMapData);
    });
});;
```

Comment: Even more than that, the injected leafletData that is passed to the controller shadows the declared var, which is left undefined when it is accessed in the test.